# How to read and assign data to a class object which has list as its member

Tags: java, list

I have 2 domain classes

```
class Country {
    String name;
    List<State> statelist;

    public addState(String statename) {
        statelist.add(statename);
    }

   //getters and setters etc
}

class State implements Comparable {
    String name;
    // better setter compareTO etc
}
```

Then

```
public class Main {
}
```

Input :

```
4
India|TamilNadu
USA|Texas
USA|Alaska
India|Punjab
```

Output should be Countries in alphabetical order with states within each country listed under it, again in alphabetical order.

```
India
 Punjab
 TamilNadu
USA
 Alaska
 Texas
```

I am new to java. Not sure how to read and assign the value to Country class. Any suggestions

Comment: hi Sivabalan, i have posted a solution under. Please let me know if it is useful or not

Answer (score 0):

You can't add `String` to `ArrayList` that consist of states. You have to make an instance of `State`, assign a string to it, and then add `State` to `statelist`

```
 public void addState(String statename)
    {

    State state = new State();
    state.name = statename;
    statelist.add(state);

    }

    public State getStateByName(String stateName){

    for(State state : statelist) 
       if(state.name == stateName) 
          return state;

     }
```

Comment: @SivabalanDivya what do you mean to read? You access the state's name via `state.name` if it is public member, if it's not, then you write a public getter for it.

Comment: I need to know how to check if the country name is already available in and the state alone is added to the statelist. If country is not available then how to create a new entry for country name and the state in statelist

Answer (score 0):

First of all the advice given by wdc in his answer is absolutely correct. You will have to make that change. You should also add a parameterized constructor for the Country class which takes a String and stores the name as that string.

Check the [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class to know about how to read from read from Stdin. The approach would be as follows:

1. Using the scanner class read the first number using nextInt().
2. Loop through that many times and each time read the next Country|State pair using next() method of the Scanner class.
3. Split the above string using the "|" as the delimiter. (Check the split() method in the String Class)
4. You will also need a Set of Countries so that you do not create multiple objects for the same country.
5. If the Set contains the Country just obtain the object from the set and add the corresponding state to the country. If not then just create a new Country object for that country, add the corresponding state and add it to the Set.

```js
public static void main(String[] args){
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Set<Country> country_set = new HashSet<>();
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        String input = sc.next();
        String[] pair = input.split("|");
        if(country_set.contains(pair[0]){
            country_set.get(pair[0]).addState(pair[1]));
        }
        else{
            Country temp = new Country(pair[0]);
            temp.addState(pair[1]);
            country_set.add(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The statement  country_set.get(pair[0].addState(pair[1])); IS showing compilation error

Comment: Cannot find symbol at country_set.get(pair[0].  The . Symbol

Comment: I had missed a bracket. Try now.

Answer (score 0):

As you would be comparing String ultimately, you dont need to implement Comparable. Try the below code:

```
package stackOverflow;

public class State extends Country  {
    String stateName;
    String countryName;

    public State(String stateName,String countryName) {
        super(countryName,stateName);
        this.stateName = stateName;
        this.countryName = countryName;

    }



}
```

and the other class is :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Country
{
 public static HashMap<String, String> countryMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
 public static ArrayList<String> countries = new ArrayList<String>();

public Country(String cntryName, String stateName ) {
    if(countryMap.get(cntryName)!= null) {
        countryMap.put(cntryName,countryMap.get(cntryName)+","+stateName);
    }else {
        countryMap.put(cntryName,stateName);
    }
    if(!countries.contains(cntryName))
        countries.add(cntryName);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

  ArrayList<State> states = new ArrayList<State>();


  states.add(new State("TamilNadu","India"));
  states.add(new State("Texas","USA"));
  states.add(new State("Punjab","India"));
  states.add(new State("Alaska","USA"));

  Collections.sort(countries);
  //or  Collections.sort(countries, (p,p1)->(p.compareTo(p1)));
  for(String country : countries) {
      System.out.println("country is :"+country+" and the states are :"+countryMap.get(country));
  }

}
    }
```